# How to export huge JSON data from SQL Server into multiple separate rows?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, database, format

I am using the `FOR JSON` method to extract the table data in JSON format but it exports every thing in one single row. Instead, I want to have a JSON line per record, I tried using `FOR JSON PATH` but that doesn't work,

Below is the sample of what I am trying to do, can't paste the whole query due to privacy reasons. Please guide me if anyone has come across the same scenario

```
SELECT 
    orderId,
    customerid
FROM
    T
FOR JSON PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want each row to be returned separately as a new JSON object, you need to nest `FOR JSON PATH` like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    (SELECT
        T.orderId,
        T.customerid
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)
FROM
    T;
```

Comment: Probably want to add WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER to the JSON PATH.

Comment: Hey @Charlieface Thank you so much now it works like a charm. Much appreciated answer

Answer (score 1):

SSMS is not handling JSON properly.

You should use **Azure Data Studio** for that. It is installed together with the latest SSMS 18.8. Or independently, on its own.

[Download and install Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver15)

File -> Save will produce a nicely formatted and indented JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

> I am using the FOR JSON method to extract the table data in JSON format but it exports every thing in one single row.

No it doesn't.  It's not one row per JSON doc, as you are creating one large JSON doc, but the data is actually broken over multiple rows.  SSMS just puts it back together for display.

If you want one JSON doc per row, see @Charlieface's answer.

Comment: Yes I followed @charlieface and it works now. thank you for the array wrapper suggestion